# TSA: Why singing hash(hash(data),t)?

Tags: timestamp, trust

Why does a TSA first appends the timestamp and hashes the combination of timestamp and data? This product is then signed and send to the client back with the timestamp. Why not signing hash + timestamp?

Comment: What is a TSA? What protocol or system is this question about?

Comment: @PieterWuille Trusted Time Stamping. TSA is Timestamping Authority.

Comment: I don't know about that, but a quick search tells me you're maybe talking about RFC 3161? If so, that seems off topic here.

Comment: @PieterWuille
Yeah. this is the protocol. But I do not understand the design choise.

Comment: This seems unrelated to Bitcoin.

Comment: I thought this stackexchange is about everything dealing with consensus, byzantine, trusting third parties, etc. ... (everything bitcoin is built on)?

Comment: It is about technologies that apply to supporting the bitcoin currency. Timestamping in an abstract sense certainly does, but not the specifics of RFC 3161, which is unrelated to how timestamping services for Bitcoin work.

Comment: If u go to wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_timestamping
It seems like a general concept. I just want to know if I forget something, or about advandatages, such a design choice has.
Maybe privacy, scalability, ... I do not know. :/